# Derivative of matrix with respected to vector (matrix in se(3))

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives

We know that the matrix $A \in SE(3)$ can be written in exponential formula, i.e.

$$e^{M} = \begin{bmatrix} R_{3\times3} & \vec{t} \\\vec{0}^T & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} [\vec{\omega}]_{\times} & V^{-1}\vec{t} \\\vec{0}^T & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
,where $\omega = [\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z]^T$ can be retrieved from rodrigues' formula. and

$$V = I_3 + \frac{1-cos{\theta}}{\theta^2}[\vec{\omega}]_{\times} + \frac{\theta - \sin{\theta}}{\theta^3}[\vec{\omega}]_{\times}^2$$

We know that matrix $V$ is a function of $[\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z]$. I wish to know how to compute the derivative of $V$ with respected to each element. My attempt is to use the definition of derivative.

$$f^\prime = \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

However, even with the help from wolframalpha, I couldn't simplify the term. The image below shows my attempt with wolframalpha for the second term. Does anyone here know more convenient method of doing this? Thank you very much. [image: a]

Answer (score 1):

Not enough reputation point to comment, so I'll post this as an "answer".

The phi-function is 
$$\phi(x) = \frac {e^{x}-1} {x}$$

The function you're attempting to take the derivative of is a matrix version of the phi-function
$$V=\phi \big([\vec{\omega}]_{\times}\big)$$

That's going to be difficult.  Even more difficult is that fact that you want a matrix-by-vector derivative.